# ajax object server data extract

Tags: c#, ajax

Currently i am adding this code into the post the data is posting across how would i be able to post this data across to the server not as a object but individually string.
OR
 how would i call this data in the object using c#

```
var ajaxData = {
                   'Id': document.getElementsByName("Id").value,
                   'ClientId': document.getElementsByName("ClientId").value,
                   'GAUserName': document.getElementsByName("GAUserName").value,
                   'GAPassword': document.getElementsByName("GAPassword").value,
                   'Email': document.getElementsByName("Email").value,
                   'Profiles': document.getElementsByName("Profiles").value,
                   'AppKey ': document.getElementsByName("AppKey").value,
                   'SchTime': document.getElementsByName("SchTime").value,
                   'IsActive': document.getElementsByName("IsActive").value

               };

               $.ajax({
                   url: postUrl,
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: ajaxData,
                   success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                       alert('Data has been chnaged');
                   }
               });
```

Comment: What? It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish. Maybe if you post the code you've tried to use to do what you want to do, it'd help.

Comment: I want to now how i would be able to cal this object into c#, or take into c# the data as separate strings

Comment: as currentlt the data that is passed though is nulll